# Django Model copy with ManyToManyField

Tags: django

Trying to copy a Django model with ManyToManyField.

the model is

```
class Book(models.Model):
    cats = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
```

the view:

```
for book in books:
    book.name = "New Name"
    messageinfo = message.save()

    msg = Book(title=book.title, subject=book.subject)
    msg.save()
```

sort of works till here, makes a copy of book

the following gets an error

```
    for cat in book.cats:
            info = Category.objects.get(id=cat.id)
            msg.cats.add(info)
```

Error it produces

```
    TypeError at /
    'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
book.cats.all()
```

[Example usage](http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/models/many_to_many/) and [docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#many-to-many-relationships).