# Copying ManyToMany fields from one model instance to another

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-1.4

I'm new to django, and as a learning app, I'm building an expense logging application.

In my models I have three classes that look like this (I simplified them slightly for brevity):

```
class AbstractExpense(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    amount      = models.IntegerField()
    category    = models.ForeignKey('Category')
    tags        = models.ManyToManyField('Tag')
    insert_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta(object):
        abstract = True

class Expense(AbstractExpense):
    date        = models.DateField('Date')

class RecurringExpense(AbstractExpense):
    FREQUENCY_CHOICES = (('D', 'daily'),
                         ('W', 'weekly'),
                         ('M', 'monthly'),
                         ('Y', 'yearly'))
    start_date = models.DateField(blank=False)
    end_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    last_check = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    frequency = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=1, choices=FREQUENCY_CHOICES)
```

`RecurringExpense` is just a template: when the system realises that the time to insert a recurring expense (e.g.: the rent) it should take the info in the template and copy them in a new instance of the `Expense` class. Here's the relevant bit from the `RecurringExpense` method in charge of the work:

```
Expense(description=self.description,
        amount=self.amount,
        category=self.category,
        # tags=self.tags,
        date=expense_date).save()
```

The above works flawlessly, but if I uncomment the `tags=self.tags` line, django complains and throw the following error:

```
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value: 'tags' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
Exception Location: <snip>/django/db/models/base.py in __init__, line 367
```

I know [I could create a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439727/django-model-copy-with-manytomanyfield) to work around this problem, but I wonder if there is a more elegant way that would allow me to perform the same at once....

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The simpliest method I could come up with:

```
e = Expense(description=self.description,
            amount=self.amount,
            category=self.category,
            date=expense_date)
e.save()
e.tags = self.tags.all()
```

Comment: You can also replace `Expense(...)`/`e.save()` with `Expense.objects.create(...)`

Comment: This might not work if you have a large number of tags (SQL driver dependent). In this case you can iterate in large chunks over all tags in order to add them.

Answer (score 21):

You cannot set an m2m field directly like that when creating a model instance. Try the following instead:

```
expense = Expense(description=self.description,
        amount=self.amount,
        category=self.category,
        date=expense_date)
expense.save()
expense.tags.add(*self.tags.all())
```

You can check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/ for more examples on how to work with many-to-many relationships.

Comment: Hi and thank you for your answer. Is there a specific reason why you use the `.add()` method in combination with the unpacking of the list, rather than a simple assignment (see my own answer)?

Comment: I often don't need to replace the existing m2m relation set, just add to it, so more used to that. For your use case indeed assignment is simpler and should work fine, as `ManyRelatedObjectsDescriptor` does `.clear` + `.add(*values)` behind the scenes when you do an assignment.

Comment: What's the * doing here? I see that it works with it, and doesn't work without it, but I'm struggling to see documentation on why...

Comment: @awidgery This is a basic functionality of Python, see https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists
"unpacks" a list into function arguments.